# If condition is true print text in input field with specific ID

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Noob in need of some input here. I've spent some hours now trying to get this to work, with both PHP and javascript and this is where i'm at now.

I want to get an input field to show a specific text based on a condition. If the digit in input field 'ebctotal' is within the range 1-4, then show the text "very pale" in input field 'hue'.

Code:

```
function getHue() {
var ebc = document.getElementById("ebctotal").value;
if (ebc >= 1 && ebc <= 4) {
    // insert text "Very pale" into element with id 'hue' 
document.getElementById('hue').value;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
// print text in this field
<input class="input" type="text" id="hue" size="7" maxlength="20">
// based on value of this field
<input class="input" type="text" id="ebctotal" size="7" maxlength="20">
```

Am I on the right track?

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide your HTML please ?

Comment: @Magicprog.fr Editted with html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether length of "ebc" between 1-4 then try like;

```
function getHue() {
   var ebc = document.getElementById("ebctotal").value;
   if (ebc.length>=1 && ebc.length<=4) {
       document.getElementById('hue').value='Very pale';
    }
}
```

or whether value of "ebc" between 1-4 then try like;

```
function getHue() {
   var ebc = parseInt(document.getElementById("ebctotal").value);
   if (ebc>=1 && ebc<=4) {
       document.getElementById('hue').value='Very pale';
    }
}
```